# How to change the timezone manipulate the timestamp of created_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an eloquent query that I would want to change the `created_at` to subtract 2 hours.

The query is

```
AirtimeTransaction::select('airtime_transactions.id',
   'airtime_transactions.created_at',
   'airtime_transactions.request_id', 
   DB::raw('IF(airtime_transactions.result_desc IS NULL or airtime_transactions.result_desc = "", "Failed", airtime_transactions.result_desc) as result_desc'))
->groupBy('airtime_transactions.id');
```

I would like to subtract two hours from the answer to `airtime_transactions.created_at`

Anyone assist here

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [Eloquent Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `AirtimeTransaction` model:

```php
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($createdAt)
    {
        return (new Carbon($createdAt))->subHours(2);
    }
```

Comment: This leads to ErrorException: Undefined index: created_at

Comment: @user6721269 I've update my example to create a Carbon instance. Try it now.

Comment: Still getting `ErrorException: Undefined index: created_at`